# Find total amount for each agent from nested nodes in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am learning on the Job and I would like to display total amount an agent has sold. This is a nested object as the json below indicates.
Thanks in advance

```
  "68600" : {
     "name" : "Pablo picasso",
    "sales" : {
      "-MVFp1JDHikxD1d-6q2w" : {
        "amount" : 650,
        "id" : "-MVFp1JDHikxD1d-6q2w",
        "timestamp" : 1615190041147
      },
      "-MVFp505IskBRrooof-Z" : {
        "amount" : 840,
        "id" : "-MVFp505IskBRrooof-Z",
        "timestamp" : 1615190056307
      },
      "-MVFpE2Q93tbDgQmVFQE" : {
        "amount" : 650,
        "id" : "-MVFpE2Q93tbDgQmVFQE",
        "timestamp" : 1615190093320
      },
      "-MVFqRncyoTuk26MvhJU" : {
        "amount" : 1700,
        "id" : "-MVFqRncyoTuk26MvhJU",
        "timestamp" : 1615190411796
      }
    }
  },
  "786500" : {

    "sales" : {
      "-MVQIKvKzr_BRCbP2nlv" : {
        "amount" : 655,
        "id" : "-MVQIKvKzr_BRCbP2nlv",
        "timestamp" : 1615365757283
      }
    }
  },
```

Below is my implementation, when i console.log it is displaying the wrong tally.

```
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
   const db = firebase.database();

    db.ref('sellers').on('value', snapshot => {
    const val = snapshot.val();
    let idx = 0;
    for (let key in val)
    {
       const agentSales = val[key]['sales'];

        for (let salesObj in agentSales)
        {
        _sales = agentSales[salesObj].amount;
        total  = total + _sales;
        // console.log(_sales);

            // for(let total in _sales){
            //   console.log(_sales[total].amount);
            // }

        }


        //if(snapshot.hasChildren())
        //{
        // var total = 0;
        // snapshot.forEach(function(item){
        //   total += item.child('amount').val();
        // });
        // console.log(total);
        //}
    }
  });
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) is a pretty good place to start, as are some of the *many* tutorials out there. If you're are having trouble making your code work, please edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read that link please for guidance on maximizing the chances that someone can help).

Comment: Yes I have tried the code above. thanks

Comment: 1) There is no `sellers` node in the JSON you shared. Is that JSON the value of the `sellers` node? 2) You're saying "when i `console.log`  it is displaying the wrong tally." Can you include the `console.log` in your question? What is it displaying? What do you expect it to display?

Comment: i am getting 560 
1210
2050
2700
4400
5055
5420

Comment: Please read my entire comment and take all steps: 1) include the code that logs (uncommented) in your post, 2) its output too, 3) what output you expect instead. 4) Note that the current uncommented code never set `total` to 0, so it keeps whatever value it had before.